# How can I find my GPS device on map?

Tags: c#, gps

I need a GPS device and I want to connect it with C# application, to track it in map. Anyone to tell me where to start?

Comment: This is why there are search engines. SO is for situations where you have a particular problem and *any* of your attempts *failed* to yield what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the GPS locations depends on the device you are using. As for tracking it on a map, you can you the `gMap.Net` module (https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) which allows you to utilize Google Maps in your application